# Android Facebook integration: Send message to a particular friend on FB Messenger

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

Assuming I have Facebook login in my android app allowing me to access user's friend list and their user ids, Is there any way I can directly open FB Messenger (if installed) showing either

1) A new message screen with "To" field pre filled with a friend's name and some default message or link attached to body OR

2) The chat screen (chat history) of the user with a particular friend and pre filled message or link attached to the body

So that the user just needs to verify the recipient and message (and modify if required) and clicks on send button to send the message.

The important requirement is **able to tap on a friends name in my app and open the FB Messenger to send a message directly to him/her without having to select/type his/her name from my Messenger friend list again**.

Any help or guidance would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not possible. And prefilling message is not allowed even if it was possible. Please read Facebook Platform Policy

Comment: Thanks @WizKid.  We cannot fill in messages but we can attach a link, right ?

Comment: How about prefilling recipient ? Or opening the chat page of recipient ?

Comment: (Assuming we have the user id of the recipient and he/she is a friend on Facebook and also using my app)